# UICollectionView with no XIB, UICollectionViewCell with XIB

Tags: objective-c, xcode, uicollectionview, xib, uicollectionviewcell

I'm trying to create a UICollectionViewCell with a XIB file for a UICollectionView i'm creating without a XIB file.

Here's how I create the CollectionView:

```
_collectionView = [[UICollectionView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.frame collectionViewLayout:collectionViewFlowLayout];
    [_collectionView setDelegate:self];
    [_collectionView setDataSource:self];
    [_collectionView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
    [_collectionView registerClass:[CustomCell class] forCellWithReuseIdentifier:carouselItemReuseIdentifier];
    [self.view addSubview:_collectionView];
```

Here's how I call the custom cell:

```
- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    CustomCell *cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:carouselItemReuseIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];
    [cell refreshWithData];

    return cell;
}
```

In the XIB file I set the Custom Class to CustomCell - but when I load the collection view, I just see rectangles - not the XIB I created for the custom class.

Answer (score 1):

You need to register the *nib*, not the class, using `registerNib:forCellWithReuseIdentifier:`. Registering the class only means it doesn't know anything about what you've added in the nib.

Documentation [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UICollectionView_class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UICollectionView/registerNib%3aforCellWithReuseIdentifier%3a)

Answer (score 1):

In `viewDidLoad` register the nib like:

```
UINib *nib = [UINib nibWithNibName:@"MyCell" bundle: nil];
[cv registerNib:nib forCellWithReuseIdentifier:identifier];
```

and in cell method:

```
NSArray *Obj = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"CustomCellXib" owner:self options:nil];

CustomCell *cell = [nibObjects objectAtIndex:0];
```

Happy Coding :)

Comment: 50% there. Registering the nib is correct, but the collection view handles loading it when it dequeues, so the second part is not necessary.

Answer (score 0):

Try loading xib cell like below

```
NSArray *nibObjects = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"CustomCellXib" owner:self options:nil];

CustomCell *cell = = [nibObjects objectAtIndex:0];
```

Comment: aren't I loosing the dequeue this way?

Comment: CustomCell *cell = deque...(your code which in this line) and than write code of nsarray which is in answer and than cell =[nibObjects objectAtIndex:0];  or you can also check condition if(cell == nil){write first line which is in this ans and than cell =[nibObjects objectAtIndex:0];}

Comment: I rolled back the edit to your question as it was basically a rewrite by another user. I hope that's ok.

Comment: @Nisha - don't rewrite an entire answer in an edit. I can't believe that was approved.

Comment: ... Though both versions of the answer are wrong. Where would you get an opportunity to use this code?

Answer (score -1):

register the class using the following statement:

```
[_collectionView registerClass:[UICollectionViewCell class] forCellWithReuseIdentifier: carouselItemReuseIdentifier];
```

Comment: This exact code is already in the question, and it's the cause of the problem in the first place, so -1